# Develop an audio unit plugin using Xcode's template

Tags: xcode, audiounit

I am attempting to wrap my head around Xcode's audio unit extension template (found in the new target interface). I have loosely followed [this](https://audiokitpro.com/auv3-midi-tutorial-part1/) tutorial to get the basics down but I am having trouble getting the UI functioning. When loading into Logic Pro X, the unit looks like this: [image]

My guess it that it's not loading the UI properly. How might I go about fixing this?

Alternatively, am I doing the whole thing wrong?

[Current AudioUnit.m file](https://gist.github.com/CliftonMarien/29ebf6911f04404870ab2c70ff63d71e) (GitHub Gist)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried contacting the author of that tutorial?

Logic does not grok AUv3 MIDI right now. Maybe in the next version.

That gist is missing a bit of set up. Take a look at the tutorial repos.